# How to get count of array of word occurrences in a sentence

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have array of string as an input to search and list of sentences which I read from Excel. I find out the sentences from this list which contains my array of strings. But now I need to sort the sentences based on the word matching count.

For example, my array of string contains 3 words.

```
string[] srchList = {"smartphone" , "4GB" , "Amoled"}
```

**sentence list from excel:**

- "Realme1 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM capacity."
- "Realme2 smartphone has LCD screen with 4GB RAM capacity."
- "Realme3    phone has LCD screen with 6GB RAM capacity."
- "Realme4 phone has LED    screen with 6GB RAM capacity."
- "Realme5 smartphone has super Amoled    screen with 4GB RAM and 4GB
  extended memory capacity"

****sentences matching with array of string:****

1. "Realme1 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM capacity."
2. "Realme2 smartphone has LCD screen with 4GB RAM capacity."
3. "Realme5 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM and 4GB extended memory capacity."

I find out the sentence which contains my array of string and added the sentences to the list but now I need to sort the list based on the word matching count.

For example, 3rd sentence in my list has 4 words which matches with array of string. And 1st sentence matches 3 times then finally 2nd sentence matches only 2 times. Now I need to sort my list based on the count.

Is there any simple way to sort the list based on the count of occurrences?

```
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    if (null != row && row.ItemArray.Length > 0)
    {
        List<string> strRes = row.ItemArray.Where(itmArr => srchList.Any(wrd => itmArr.ToString().ToLower().Contains(wrd.ToString()))).OfType<string>().ToList();

        if (null != strRes && strRes.Count > 0)
        {
            searchResult.AddRange(strRes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GroupBy count, orderby count?

Comment: You'd need to calculate the count rather than just checking if any of the words match. Something similar to `srchList.Sum(x => itmArr.ToString().Split().Count(y => y ==x))`  Also currently you'd match partial words too.  Like if one of your words is "up" it would match a sentence like "It's upside down", not sure if that's what you want or not.

Comment: @juharr - Yes, you're right. I want partial match too. I want both count and matching sentences.

Comment: That will make the counting logic a bit more complex then as the snippet I put is an exact word match count.

Comment: @juharr Is it possible to again iterate through the result list and array of string to sort the list again? I am fine with rewriting the entire logic. Just I need the result set to display the highest matching result set in the UI.

Comment: The best bet is to write a method that will take the sentence an a word and return a count.  You can then use that in your query and filter on anything with a count > 0 and then order on the count.  The method would basically do something like `while(offest = sentence.IndexOf(word, offset) >= 0) { count++; offset += word.Length}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that will count how many times a substring occurs in a string, not allowing for the substring to overlap (so "aa" would be found in "aaaa" twice rather than 3 times) which seems to be what you'd want anyway.

```
public static int CountSubstrings(string sentence, string word)
{
    int count = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while((offset = sentence.IndexOf(word, offset)) >= 0)
    {
        count++;
        offset+=word.Length;
        if(offset >= sentence.Length) break;
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

With that you can do the following Linq code to get the counts and filter and order on it.

```
string[] srchList = {"smartphone" , "4GB" , "Amoled"};
string[] sentences =
{
    "Realme1 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM capacity.",
    "Realme2 smartphone has LCD screen with 4GB RAM capacity.",
    "Realme3 phone has LCD screen with 6GB RAM capacity.",
    "Realme4 phone has LED screen with 6GB RAM capacity.",
    "Realme5 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM and 4GB extended memory capacity"
};

var results = sentences
    .Select(x => new { Sentence = x, Count = srchList.Sum(y => CountSubstrings(x, y)) })
    .Where(x => x.Count > 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => x.Sentence)
    .ToList();
```

With the results being the following

> Realme2 smartphone has LCD screen with 4GB RAM capacity.

> Realme1 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM capacity.

> Realme5 smartphone has super Amoled screen with 4GB RAM and 4GB extended memory capacity

If you need them in order of highest count first then just change `OrderBy` to `OrderByDescending`.